# How to eliminate sub or function not defined error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this VBA code in excel, and while saving it in this workbook, I am getting **sub or function not defined** error and the offset line is highlighted. I am entirely new to VBA and I don't know to debug this, please help me out with this.

Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
Cancel As Boolean)

'######################################################################################
'Employee Name Validation Started
'######################################################################################
Activate
Range("B2").Select
exceptionCount = 0
Do Until ActiveCell.Address = "$B$10"
' Check if the Employee Name is Not Null
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
totalExceptions = 1
exceptionCount = 1
Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'Highlight with Yellow Color
Else
Interior.ColorIndex = 15 'Retain Grey Color
End If
Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
If exceptionCount = 1 Then
exceptionString = exceptionString + vbCrLf & "- Employee Name Cannot be Empty"
End If
'#######'Employee Name Validation Completed '##############################################


End Sub
```

Comment: Your first issue is `Offset(1, 0).Select`. 'Offset' is a `Range.Property`. You have ***not*** assigned it to any range.

Comment: probably `Activate` is not defined and causing your issue. Anyhow, I strongly encourage you to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba and rework your code. And use `Option Explicit` so that the compiler can inform you about such error.

Comment: Sure will check it out and try to improve my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to mention where you have the error, apparently it was in this line:

```
Offset(1, 0).Select
```

This makes sense, because `Offset()` is not some function, it's a property of a range.

Most probably you want to use the offset of the cell you have selected, which you can write as:

```
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

Good luck

Comment: Yeah, setting offset to an ActiveCell, made this issue solve. Thank you so much.